# How can I access errors in response from component porps with apollo client

Tags: graphql, react-apollo

After I send fetch query to the graphql server, server side returns errors like this [graphql response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkBKT.png)

But React component doesn't show errors in their props.
[component props](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5Mw9.png)

I want to control how component run actions based on error code.
For example If component doesn't fetch any data, mustation action will run. And then I want to control it again based on fail or success.

```
class Room extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    if (this.props.data.loading) {
      return (<div>Loading</div>)
    }
    if (this.props.errors.code == "bad_request") {
      //redirect to form
    }
    if (this.props.errors.code == "not_found") {
      // run mutaion query
    }

    return (
      <div>
         Room name is {room.length} 
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Does Anybody know how to access response value or any other best error handling?

Answer (score 0):

You can access error in data.error object see this link for details
http://dev.apollodata.com/react/api-queries.html#graphql-query-data-error

Comment: Oh, thanks! I overlooked object inside graphqlErrors. I understand :)

Comment: Great, Please Accept answer if it is correct and helped you. Thanks